# Mapping a key in VIM

Tags: vim

I've tried:

```
:map <F2> :.y" :g/<C-R>"/d<CR>
```

No luck :(

What this does, yank the current line into register "
Then, globally, delete lines that match exactly the line in the register.
It works dandy when I do it manually.

```
:vmap <F2> ["]yy<ESC><ESC> :g/<C-R>"/d<CR>
```

Similar to above - I select a few words, whatever - I make a selection, then yank it to register ".  I then globally, delete the lines that match whats in the register.
It works dandy when I do it manually.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well - I tried do do a simple map from the manual, wouldn't work.. Turns out xubuntu, doesn't install vim by default - but vi.  Anyways - after install vim and having stuff work sorta .......I'm at least on the right track now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - make sure you're using vim :)

```
vim --version
```

Here's the mapping I was going for.  As I go through lots of data in log files, this will be incredibly useful.  Select the area you want to eliminate, then  and all instances of highlight area is done for.

NOTE: This does *NOT* go through the highlighted text and escape any regex characters.  So a /, *, ^ will foul it up.

```
:map <F2> y:g/<C-R>"/d<CR>
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

You might try this for the first one:

```
:nnorempa <F2> :silent exe "g/".getline(".")."/d"<CR>
```

For the second, something like this if you want to delete only the words:

```
:vmap <F7> y:silent exe "%s/".@"."//g"<CR>
```

And this if you want to delete the matching lines:

```
:vmap <F7> y:silent exe "g/".@"."/d"<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have remapped F2 to `:.y" :`*etc*. You need `<cr>` not a simple space. If you type `:.y"` in vim and don't hit ENTER but space, nothing will happen.

So:

```
:nnoremap <f2> :.y"<CR>:g/<C-R>"/d<CR>
```

could do it.

Still, warning, if your line contains any of `/\*[~$^.` this could fail. You could use the expression register in order to escape in-place:

```
:nnoremap <f2> :.y"<CR>:g/<c-r>=escape(@", '/\*[~$^.')<cr>/d<cr>
```

Still better, without overwriting your default (`"`) register is:

```
:nnoremap <f2> :g/^<c-r><c-o>=escape(getline('.'), '/\*[~$^.')<CR>$/d<cr>
```

which will delete all identical lines. Still note that `'ignorecase'` or `'smartcase'` matter.